# Is there something like js hoisting for class definitions in python?

Tags: python, class, types

I've got 2 class definitions:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, bar: Bar):
    # some code

class Bar:
  def __init__(self, foo: Foo):
    # some more code
```

I want to specify the types of the arguments. When I try to run that code I get "using variable 'Bar' before assignment" error.

Is it possible to tell the interpreter that `Bar` is defined a few lines below?

Comment: No, there is no hoisting. However, for type annotations in older versions you can simply use a string, in newer versions, `from __future__ import annotations` which will give you the behavior of postponed evaluation of annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Python version 3.7 or later you can add the following to the top of your file

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7

Comment: ...and for prior versions, simply use a string with the class name. The 3rdy party tools that deal with annotations will handle that.